# Use migrations like in Django in Rails models

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, ruby-on-rails-3

I was developing in both **RoR** and **Django** based projects, and I don't like the way how RoR deals with **migrations**. For example, if I make huge changes to my models over 2 years, in Django I can delete all migrations and make new, single file, basing on actual state of my models. In RoR I will have, like 50 files, where some of them may be absolutely redundant (correct me if I'm wrong).

I would like to have RoR app, that would **create migration basing on models, like in Django** (so I assume models would need some information about fields).

Is there any gem/framework to RoR, that would add such feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `db/schema.rb` file keeps track of the current state, and you can delete your migrations at any point and use the `rake db:schema:load` task to load the `db/schema.rb` into your DB.